# If exist folder batch not working

Tags: batch, batch-file

Please help to rectify my batch code where goes wrong. The purpose is to check where the folder is then delete those files older than 180 days. When It runs, it does not pop up anything.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 Echo Delete Files older than 180 days
 if exist "D:\HKvbrMain\Log\" (
 echo Folder in Drive D
 forfiles /p "D:\HKvbrMain\Log" /m *.* /d -180 /c "cmd /c del /f /q 
 @path"
 ) else (
 echo Folder in Drive C
 forfiles /p "%systemdrive%\HKvbrMain\Log" /m *.* /d -180 /c "cmd /c 
 del /f /q @path"
 )
 echo %errorlevel%
 Pause
```

endlocal

Comment: Did you manually run it in a cmd to have a look what the actual error is?

Comment: I would break it up in sections (and add *pause* in between) and check command output, see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to add the second condition to make it works.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 Echo Delete Files older than 180 days
 if exist "D:\HKvbrMain\Log\" (
 echo Folder in Drive D
 forfiles /p "D:\HKvbrMain\Log" /m *.* /d -180 /c "cmd /c del /f /q 
 @path"
 ) else (
 if exist "%systemdrive%\HKvbrMain\Log\" (
 echo Folder in Drive C
 forfiles /p "%systemdrive%\HKvbrMain\Log" /m *.* /d -180 /c "cmd /c 
 del /f /q @path"
 )
 )
 echo %errorlevel%
 Pause
```